# After adding composite i wasn't able to Save Records

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

Code below was working fine until adding the composite key. After Composite Key added i can only edit existing records and unable to add new records. I want `Code` and `CompanyId` columns to be Composite Keys.

*This is the Error:*

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
>   'CostCenters' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

After looking for solutions in SO and added below line(still no progress):

`Property(c => c.CompanyId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`

**Model:**

```
public class CostCenter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

**FluentAPI:**

```
public CostCenterConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => new { c.Code, c.CompanyId });
        Property(c => c.CompanyId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(c => c.Code)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(255);
        Property(c => c.Description)
        .HasMaxLength(1200);
        HasRequired(c => c.Company)
        .WithMany(c => c.CostCenters)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Save(CostCenter costcenter)
    {
        try
        {
            if (costcenter.Id == 0)
                _context.CostCenters.Add(costcenter);
            else
            {
                var costcenterInDb = _context.CostCenters.Single(c => c.Id == costcenter.Id);
                costcenterInDb.Code = costcenter.Code;
                costcenterInDb.Description = costcenter.Description;
                costcenterInDb.CompanyId = costcenter.CompanyId;
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "CostCenters");
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
            this.ModelState.AddModelError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
            return View("CostCenterForm");
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException e) when ((e?.InnerException?.InnerException as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)?.Number == 2601)
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("Code", "Item with such '" + costcenter.Code + "' already exist");
            return View("CostCenterForm");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error msg is clear, you are trying to insert a value to an identity column while IDENTITY_INSERT  set to on.

Comment: how to set it `on` using FluentAPI? by enabling identity_insert will solve my issue?

Comment: read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)

Comment: Also why you are trying to insert a value to an identity column, why don't you let SQL Server do it for you?

Comment: Thanks for the link..

Comment: your db schema does not match your model, IDENTITY seems to be on CompanyId (I assume) in your db whereas you set the DatabaseGeneratedOption to None. remove the identity constraint from any columns you don't need it on, or use Identity insert (remember to explicitly use transactions, otherwise EF will wrap your statements in its own transactions and your changes won't have any effect) to insert these.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CostCenters' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

The error message was clear an helpful too, you are trying to insert a value to an `IDENTITY` column while **[IDENTITY_INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)** is set to `OFF`.

I would suggest to remove that value and let SQL Server do the job, but if you insist to insert the value then you should set `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` and set it to `OFF` again just after you finish:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema.TableName ON;  
GO  
-- do your insert
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema.TableName OFF;  
GO
```